# #Return same screen after refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, reload

I am developing a page that use a ajax request to read a JSON file and I am displaying it
by looping on clicks
but when I refresh page it returns to first screen is there anyway to return the same screen after
I refresh
please no JQUERY

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you have worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: of course the data will disappear when you reload the page because you didn't fetched them during page load. unless during ajax call is that you'll modify the database so that during page load, the system can detect that changes in the db so that it will decide to display those data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have made a "framework" for maintaining the stat of your page.

The AJAX request happens when the hash in the URL changes (here the state is "state1": `http://example.org/#state1`). There is an event listener for the `hashchange` event and a function `fetshdata()`.

When clicking the button "Get Data", the hash will change, the `hashchange` event will happen and the function `fetshdata()` will be called.

If the page is reloaded (this is your problem) the "state" of the page is maintained in the hash (the hash is still in the URL). To tricker the `hashchange` event I made the hashchange event "by hand" and dispatch it on the window.

The state of the page could also be maintained in localStorage, but the advantage with the hash in the URL is that the hash change becomes part of the history in the browser and you can save/send/link to the URL etc.

```js
const data = 'data:application/json;base64,W3sidGl0bGUiOiJJdGVtIDEifSx7InRpdGxlIjoiSXRlbSAyIn0seyJ0aXRsZSI6Ikl0ZW0gMyJ9XQ==';

var content;

const fetchdata = hash => {
  let url = hash; //use the hash as part of the AJAX request (not implemented)
  fetch(data).then(res => res.json()).then(json => {
    content.innerHTML = '';
    json.forEach(item => {
      content.innerHTML += `<p>${item.title}</p>`;
    });
  });
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
  content = document.getElementById('content');
  document.getElementById('btn_load').addEventListener('click', e => {
    location.hash = 'newstate';
  });
  
  document.getElementById('btn_reload').addEventListener('click', e => {
    location.reload();
  });
  
  if(location.hash){
    let event = new Event('hashchange');
    window.dispatchEvent(event);
  }
});

window.addEventListener('hashchange', e => {
  let hash = location.hash.substring(1);
  fetchdata(hash);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn_load">Get data</button>
<button id="btn_reload">Reload</button>
<div id="content"></div>
```